# What's up with migraine auras? Why do they occur sometimes with migraines, but not always? What are they even?

Tags: physiology, migraine-auras, scotomas-blind-spots, scintilla-flashing-lights

When I was a small child, I thought I was performing magic whenever these **migraine-auras** developed, and I would ask my younger brother if he wanted to see a magic trick. I'd have him close and open his eyes, and I'd say something like, *"Viola! Do you see how colorful they are?"* He never could. I soon realized that the people around me weren't seeing these blotches of colors (**scotoma-blind spots**), flashing lights (**scintilla migraines**), and striking zig-zags (**fortification spectra**) as I was, and these seemingly "thrilling" light shows were followed by intense pain in my head. It stopped being fun. I was eventually diagnosed with migraines.

As a migraine sufferer since I was a child (now an adult in my early 30's), I have always wondered what migraine auras are exactly. They often accompany my migraines, but not always.

**What triggers migraine auras to develop in some migraine episodes, but not others?**

**What is exactly happening to the field of vision when migraine-auras occur? Is it actually obstructed or is it more of an illusion (like bordering the line of hallucinations)?**

Comment: Totally off topic, but don't use oral contraceptives when you have migraine auras as explained here http://www.medscape.com/viewarticle/589439

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Migraine auras are in a way similar to epileptic seizures; the most-accepted theory is they're caused by a depression of cortical neurons that spreads throughout the cortex during the attack.

[Cortical Spreading Depression](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/25473742)

[Migraine Aura Pathophysology](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20170844)